# Sudoer with permission denied

Tags: dovecot, sudo, find

I have a user in sudoers which has entry like

```
user    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/find
```

then that `user` will try to do

```
/usr/bin/find /var/mailboxes -iname mailbox@domain.net
```

but results will be something like

```
/usr/bin/find: `/var/mailboxes/d2': Permission denied
```

but when `user` will run it with sudo as

```
sudo /usr/bin/find /var/mailboxes -iname mailbox@domain.net
```

that will return path to `mailbox@domain.net`

How can I get `user` to run `find` on any directory w/o sudo command up front?

Answer (score 0):

Write a script that uses sudo (or equivalent privilege escalation) and use that instead.